# How to add variable to URL parameter in urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to visit this URL:

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=05&b=20&c=2013&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv

But instead of always being GOOG it will be whatever is inputted in the variable ticker_list like so:

When I do this, it works:

```
URL = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=05&b=20&c=2013&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv")
html = URL.read()
print (html)
```

But if I do this:

```
filename = input("Please enter file name to extract data from: ")
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()    # Read the data from the file

tickers_list = []
for line in data:
    tickers_list.append(line)   # Separate tickers into individual elements in list

print (tickers_list[0]) # Check if printing correct ticker
url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv" % str(tickers_list[0])
print (url) # Check if printing correct URL

URL = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = URL.read()
print (html)
```

And gives me this error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Am I not doing the string formatting correctly?

Comment: You don't need to loop over `data` adding everything to `tickers_list`; you can use `data` *directly* because `f.readlines()` returns a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are reading from the filename includes the newline at the end of each line (`.readlines()` does not remove it). You should remove this yourself; `str.strip()` removes all whitespace, including newlines:

```
filename = input("Please enter file name to extract data from: ")
with open(filename) as f:
    tickers_list = f.readlines()    # .readlines() returns a list *already*

print(tickers_list[0].strip())
url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv" % tickers_list[0].strip()
print(url)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

You do not need to call `str()` on the `tickers_list[0]` elements, because reading from a file already results in a list of strings. Moreover, the `%s` formatting placeholder converts its value to a string if it is not one yet.

*With* a newline (`\n` character in the `repr()` output below), you get the exact error you see:

```
>>> url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv" % 'GOOG\n'
>>> print(repr(url))
'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG\n&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv'
>>> urllib.request.urlopen(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 467, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py", line 1172, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

If you are going to process just *one* line from the file input, use `f.readline()` to read that one line and save yourself having to index a list. You still need to strip off the newline.

If you are going to process all lines, just loop directly over the input file, which yields each line separately, again *with* the newline:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for ticker_name in f:
        ticker_name = ticker_name.strip()
        url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&a=00&b=1&c=2011&d=05&e=28&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv" % ticker_name

        # etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

For manipulating urls in python I would suggest two solutions: [furl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/furl) or [URLObject](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/URLObject). Those two libraries gives you very nice interfaces to manipulate urls with ease.

Example from `furl` documentation:

```
>>> from furl import furl
>>> f = furl('http://www.google.com/?one=1&two=2')
>>> f.args['three'] = '3'
>>> del f.args['one']
>>> f.url
'http://www.google.com/?two=2&three=3'
```